# ng-stomp Whoops! Lost connection to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, stomp

I have problem with stomp connection on front-end part. This is a REST API -
back-end--> RoR(Jruby), with torquebox
- front-end --> AngularJS.

For Angular I use https://github.com/beevelop/ng-stomp

**index.html**

```
<script src="bower_components/ng-stomp/dist/ng-stomp.standalone.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('rlmuxApp', [
    'ngStomp'
  ])
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('rlmuxApp').
  controller('RequestDetailsCtrl', function ( $log,   $stomp, $scope) {
  $stomp.setDebug(function (args) {
    $log.debug(args)
  })
  function errorCallback() {
    console.log('sd');
  }
    $stomp.connect('http://localhost:8675/stomp', {
      authenticity_token: "IUuQwSA/uqSZ+CSqgCcg6H+tkRVJ2TF7pl3Q1/aY16k=",
      destination: "/stomplets/eventable/update/request/id=3",
      id: 'sub-2'
    }, errorCallback)
```

**console**

> Opening Web Socket...
>   Whoops! Lost connection to
>   http://localhost:8675/stomp request_details_controller.js:19 sd